# Django applications path

Tags: django, path

1. **Project name**: pro
2. **Project location** : /home/cha0s/pro/
3. **Applications location**:  /home/cha0s/pro/apps/    , where are folders of different apps like blog, comments etc...

**Apache configuration:**

```
 <Location "/">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE pro.settings
        PythonDebug On
        PythonPath "['/home/cha0s/','/home/cha0s/pro/apps/']
+ sys.path"  </Location>
```

So the question is :  with following configuration , to import an app in INSTALLED_APPS , for example blog  i need to write just

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    .....
    'blog',
    'gallery',
    ......
)
```

but if i take this line '/home/cha0s/pro/apps/' away from python path , by my logic then to install a module for example blog  , i need to write full path like *pro.apps.blog*  and **it should work , but it doesn't . How come ?**

***SOLUTION:***

**Thanks Lam** . Don't know how to mark Thierry Lam answer correct , so i'll just write it here.

**init**.py file must be created in apps directory even if it is just a directory with no files.  Then there is no need for *'/home/cha0s/pro/apps/'* line in apache configuration , and modules can be declared  like *pro.apps.blog*

Comment: Do you have the following file `apps/__init__.py`?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, I think it is because Django has no way to resolve "pro.apps.blog" to a real path.

Comment: @Thierry Lam   Hmmm.... you maybe right... haven't thought about it . I don't have init.py  in apps directory. Don't know why but i thought they only need to be in folders where some other files are like views.py , but now  that u mention it u may be right =) gonna try right now.

Comment: From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages): "The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file"

In other words, if you want to use a directory as part of a dotted import, it needs an `__init__.py` file, even if it contains no other files.

Comment: @Thierry Lam post your comment as an answer =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the following file `apps/__init__.py`?